# Some USB devices not working properly on a new W10 x64 machine

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive, power

Can you help me with a problem that I have with some USB devices not working properly on a new built machine.
I hope you will be able to help me, being myself a power user, but here a little lost in the face of this problem.
Feel free to comment the question if you need me to update the question with more details.

Below :

- The problem in short and detailed
- My tries and assumptions

---

### **In short**

I have a problem using my USB port when connecting an external 2,5" USB self powered hard drive. Can you help me ?

I'm using a fresh Windows 10 1909 x64 up to date, with all the manufacturer drivers installed, drivers who have nothing specially related to USB, except perhaps the AMD Chipset Driver but I don't know if it acts on this (the motherboard is an MSI B450M Mortar Max).

**The problem is** that when I connect some hard drives on an USB port, either a front port, a back port, an USB 2.0, 3.0 or a 3.1 one, with its (short) USB 3.0 cable :

- sometime (not often) the hard drive mounts and work flawlessly
- but the vast majority of time, it powers up, seems to have some difficulties with the power (I mean the LED does not blink but I can hear the disk head doing strange things), and it does not shows up into the explorer. In the hard drive manager, it is not present

This happens with branded-cased-allinone hard drives as well with self-made case hard drives, and also with some USB flash drives. Curiously other same kind of USB flash drives I have in double or triple (same model-capacity-andall) works fine.

Everything is new (except the hard drives but they were very lightly used), I have a Be Quiet TFX Power 2 Gold 300 W power supply used at 120W at max on idle and 150W at full load.

I've tested many things, including trying to force an update of the USB drivers through the device manager (but they were up to date), disabling the Power suspend of the USB ports, and many other things.

**In contrast**, all these USB devices that cause problem works perfectly when used on :

- the exact same machine using a fresh install of Linux Mint 19.1 XFCE 
  x64, no matter the USB port the devices are connected to
- another old machine running Windows 7, on front or rear USB 2.0 ports, Intel Q8300 CPU, 250W Power Supply (I use them of this machine without any problem since years)
- another old machine running Windows 7, Intel Q9450 PCU, 500W power
  supply, on front or rear USB 2.0 ports, or on some front USB 3.0 ports connected to a PCI-E card Molex powered (I use them of this machine without any problem since years)

That leads me to the conclusion that it's not a hardware related problem.

---

### **In detail**

I built a new machine that is made, for the main parts, with :

- a [MSI B450M Mortar Max](https://fr.msi.com/Motherboard/B450M-MORTAR-MAX/Specification) motherboard, with its latest BIOS (7B89v27)
- a AMD 3700X CPU
- a [Be Quiet TFX Power 2 Gold 300 W](https://www.bequiet.com/fr/powersupply/496) power supply
- 32 Gb DDR4 RAM (2 sticks)

Using Windows 10 x64 1909, up to date.
With latest nVidia drivers.
And the following MSI drivers installed :

- AMD Chipset Driver 19.10.36
- Realtek HD Universal Driver 6.0.8844.1
- Realtek PCI-E Ethernet Drivers 10.35.0510.2019

Things connected :

- an SSD
- a DVD slim burner
- a GTX1650 graphic card
- a keyboard
- a mouse
- a speaker
- a 27" screen using DVI

This machine, at idle, uses about 36-92W of power, with some spikes at about 120W.

*Idle*
[image]

This machine, at CPU full load (ex : Prime95 blend test), uses about 150W of power at its maximum.

*Full load*
[image]

That lets about 100W of available power... at full load.

---

### The problem

With the following devices, I have no problem whatever I use them on any front or rear USB 2.0, 3.0 or 3.1 ports :

- Keyboards, mouses
- USB flash drive SanDisk Ultra Fit 16 Gb
- USB flash drive SanDisk Ultra Fit 32 Gb
- USB flash drive SanDisk Ultra Fit 64 Gb
- USB flash drive SanDisk Ultra Fit 128 Gb
- USB flash drive SanDisk Extreme 16 Gb
- USB Wifi key

**But sometimes, when I connect some devices, whatever I use a front port or rear port, USB 2.0, 3.0 or 3.1 :**

- a Toshiba external 500 Gb USB 3.0 hard drive (HDTB105EK3AA), self powered, with its short, unaltered, USB 3.0 cable
- some other 2,5" hard drives inserted into external self powered USB 3.0 cases, with short and unaltered USB 3.0 cable
- one specific USB flash drive SanDisk Ultra Fit 32 Gb

**Then 9/10 times :**

- Nothing mounts
- Nothing appears in the disk manager

Talking specificly about the disks :

- The disk case LED lights up (in blue on USB 3.0 ports, in white on
  USB 2.0 ports), but does not blink as usual
- I can hear that the disk inside is "running"
- It seems that the disk looses power then restart many times

For the Toshiba hard disk for example, the power pattern is always the same :

1. it sucks about 0.3-0.46A when plugged on the USB port
2. then goes down to about 0.9-0.15A
3. then stays there, or if working, changes beetween these 2 ranges of values.

Please note that the Amp meter I use uses a 2.0 interface

*Non working USB 2.0 front*
[image]

*Non working USB 3.0 front 1*
[image]

*Non working USB 3.0 front 2*
[image]

*Non working USB 3.0 front 3*
[image]

*Working USB 3.0 back*
[image]

*Working USB 2.0 front*
[image]

But, some other 1/10 times, everything works like a charm.
As an example, all the joined pictures comes from the same boot for a test with the hard disk: once it worked, then disconnected an reconnected to the same port, it does not work.

All inner cables are well connected, not twisted or damaged, and new.
When the problem happens, W10 does not succeed to shut off.

All these devices works perfectly when used on :

- another machine running Windows 7, on front or rear USB 2.0 ports, Intel Q8300 CPU, 250W Power Supply
- another machine running Windows 7, Intel Q9450 PCU, 500W power supply, on front or rear USB 2.0 ports, or on some front USB 3.0 ports connected to a PCI-E card Molex powered

These 2 machines having at least, and far more, the same softwares installed than the W10 machine (except FarCry).

---

### **Tries and assumptions**

- Does not help : Changing the USB Selective suspend state to on or off in the Windows device manager
- Does not help : Using other USB 3.0 cables that I know they (also) work well
- Does not help : Using or not the MSI Super Charger utility
- Does not help : Installing the latest AMD chipset drivers directly from AMD instead of the MSI ones
- Does not help : I found a free hard disk and tried a new fresh and updated install with no added software and just super basic configuration (screen resolution, taskbar display, fast boost disabled, max performance power profile). No change, so I suppose that the installed softwares I had were not part of the problem, so I remove them from the above problem description.
- No problem with another OS : Same machine, same all, but USB-booting on a Linux Mint 19.1 XFCE 64 bits : whatever I can try, I can't reproduce the problem. Everything works fine, as on the other Windows 7 machines.

So my guess is that the problem is with the Windows 10 config, even if I've done nothing special : just a basic fresh install, Windows and drivers update, and a basic configuration.

Comment: I strongly believe that you have added a lot of inessential information in your question.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta I think we should appreciate that OP included everything they thought could be relevant. They are not an expect, we can't expect them to know what's essential - otherwise they probably wouldn't be asking in the first place. It also shows they've done their own research. It's nice to see such question as opposed to many which have basically no essential information, lack basic googling attempts and have severe formatting problems.

Comment: @gronostaj I guess you are right :) .

Comment: Regarding the USB drives, though self-powered, they require a minimum of watts to work properly. Not the drives per se, but the controllers. You have an awful lot of hardware connected to your PC at any given moment, and even if your power supply is supposed to be able to feed all those mouths, there's bound to be one greedier than the others who'll steal from its brethren. If the robbed party is an external HDD or SSD, then it'll start to malfunction, as I indicated earlier. Windows 10 requires more power for itself than Windows 7 used to. You want to keep the paraphernalia, lower overheads.

Comment: @Didier:I don't understand what you are talking about. I have nearly nothing connected to the PC. I guess you've read the question in a wrong way. About Windows 10, ok maybe it uses more power than Windows 7, but the Watt meter does not lies, and that seems that the power supply is more than large enough. Can you detail your solution because i don't see what you base it on ?

Comment: There is a reason it is called USB Plug and Pray.... I have one usb cable that works on all my PC's except my Dell, go figure whats wrong.

Comment: @Moab:Sure, but here using the same machine and same all, with another OS seems, to make the problem disapear. And the problem happens also with some USB flash drives, without any cables.

Comment: Maybe @BhavyaGupta was right, and you did give too much information... What I mean is, if you have all those devices (or most of them) plugged into your PC at any given moment, either directly or via hubs (more on that later), then there's bound to be some issues, power issues. Yes, Windows 10's overhead are a lot higher than 7's, that's a known fact, and the more RAM you have, the more the OS will gobble, along with CPU cycles. Maybe you should update your USB controller drivers and point Device Manager at those in your Win7 partition, if they do work better with Win7.

Comment: @Didier:Thank you for your explanation, but at evidence you've read the question really too quickly and supposed things that I don't say, even when I say the contrary, imagine things that I do even if I don't do them, and propose a solution that cannot and hasn't to be done in the exposed situation (W7 drivers to W10). Also, the fact that you say that I gave too much information put to the light that you don't seem to understand well the logic that can conduct to this kind of problem. I would be happy to explain these more to you if you want by chat.

Comment: Nah, that's fine, really, I'm sure you're doing fine as is. Good luck!

Comment: Self powered HDDs usually require more power than an white USB 2.0 port can deliver. Therefore you should never connect a self-powered HDD to white ports (this can even damage the Mainboard), only blue ports are allowed.

Comment: @Robert:Thank you and I hear what you say but you should have mentionned that this applies (and not always) only to USB 3.0 devices connected to USB 2.0 ports. It depends on the needed current for the device. If it needs only 0,5 A, an USB 2.0 port is fine. For example of a real life situation, I use USB 3.0 self powered drives on USB 2.0 ports since years and years, without any issue, but, of course, this can not be taken as an absolute proof alone of what can be done or not.

Comment: Did you try the latest AMD chipset drives directly from AMD? MSI has a tendency to keep old drivers on their website in my experience and with Windows 10 it is really important to have the drivers up2date. It all sounds if the USB controller doesn't like short power-surges while detecting a new device all that much and that is usually driver-related.

Comment: @Tonny: Yes, but without success